# Get start time and end time of the current day

Tags: java, gwt

Since there's no `Calendar` with GWT, in what way it would be possible to get the start `Date` time and end `Date` time.

Such that the start and end would be the total span of the day and in whatever timezone is set.

Comment: You can try to calculate sunrise and sunset time. [Here's the equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunrise_equation). But timezone is not enough since it (in general) is based on longitude. You also need latitude - consider polar night and day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In GWT it is safe to use `java.util.Date` as it fallbacks to JS Date. You can get inspired by [CalendarUtil](https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/blob/master/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/datepicker/client/CalendarUtil.java). For example, you can get the `00:00` of the day using `CalendarUtil.resetTime(date)` and the next day using `CalendarUtil.addDaysToDate(date, 1)`.

As `Date` transform methods are deprecated, if you are going to create some date manipulation utilities it is recommended that you check if you are running in the script mode (ie. not in the JVM, use `GWT.isScript()`) and delegate to `Calendar` or `Date` accordingly.